# Nested MVC templates

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a standard SpringMVC ModelAndView.  In one of my model objects I have an ArrayList of objects that I want to have different ui rendering capabilities. (different date formats, different css classes, divs, spans, etc....) Right now my template(view) looks like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${object.objectList}" var="item">
  ${item.toHtml}
</c:forEach>
```

My different items of course generate their own HTML.  This of course is very, very wrong as I have html code in my java code which I hate. Is there anyway to have a template(view) for each item?  Item is an abstract superclass, and I want each concrete implementation to have it's own view.

Comment: Have you thought about creating custom template tags for your items?

Comment: Sounds good, I googled SpringMVC custom template tags, but that is returning a wide range of stuff.  Can you be more specific? possibly a URL to a tutorial?  Much Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct solution, but I think that the tutorial [here](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/08/29/integrating-spring-mvc-with-jquery-for-validation-rules/) and the corresponding GitHub project [here](https://github.com/michaelisvy/ajax-samples) might give you enough of an idea to build the solution yourself.  It does not directly address your concern, but it includes a nice little tutorial on custom template tags within a Spring project.  In principal, you can create libraries of custom tags, which depending on the parameters you pass them, can create any styled HTML or JavaScript programatically, without having to store the HTML in your database (which can have its own inherent issues).